# Expansion of hypergeometric function for large arguments

Tags: asymptotics, mathematical-physics, hypergeometric-function

Does anybody know of an asymptotic expansion of $${}_2 F_1  \left( {a, \ b+\lambda\atop c+\lambda}; z \right)$$ for large $\lambda$ and $z \to 1^-$? Alternative just for bounded $z$. I found a big literature on this topic but the only expansion I found in this particular case is for large $z$. I expect some expansion with Kummer U functions, but any expansion is welcomed.

Comment: A quick look at DLMF (https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.12.iii) gives
a method and the  reference
Farid Khwaja and Olde Daalhuis (2014), Uniform asymptotic expansions for hypergeometric functions with large parameters IV
(https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0219530514500389)

Comment: I had checked DLMF before, but unfortunately it does not contain the case I'm looking at. With a transformation that I found in this article: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042702006271, my case can be brought to the first case of DLMF, but always from that article it does not seem to be a valid expansion for $z \to 1^-$. I also tried to access that article before, but I do not find a way to access it freely. Do you know of any? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Sarah_Khwaja/publication/267232610_Uniform_asymptotic_expansions_for_hypergeometric_functions_with_large_parameters_IV/links/5448b9ab0cf2d62c3052b7bb.pdf

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's actually quite helpful

Answer (score 0):

For $z$ bounded away from 1 and < 1 you can asymptotically expand the ratio of Pochhammer symbols:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(a)_k}{k!} \frac{(b+\lambda)_k}{(c+\lambda)_k} z^k
\sim   \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(a)_k}{k!} z^k \Big(1 + (b-c)\frac{k}{\lambda}+\,...\Big)$$
$$ = (1-z)^{-a} \Big( 1+ \frac{(b-c)}{1-z} \, \frac{a\,z}{\lambda} + ... \Big) $$

For $z$ very close to one you can probably use a hypergeometric identity that takes $z \to 1-z.$  There will be a region such that $z$ approaches 1 as a function of $\lambda$ in which simple functions won't work, but I'd try the simple things first.